# Onmouseover table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have script of onmouseover event, but I need not to include the `class="none"`. How to disable the onmouseover in the `class="none"`only? I set the css of `class="none".

CSS :

```
.none{
    background-color: transparent;
    border-right: #9dcc7a;
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table id="tfhover" cellspacing="0" class="tablesorter" border="1px">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="none"></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="none"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:-

```
$(function(){
  var tfrow = document.getElementById('tfhover').rows.length;
  var tbRow=[];
  for (var i=1;i<tfrow;i++) {
    tbRow[i]=document.getElementById('tfhover').rows[i];
    tbRow[i].onmouseover = function(){
      this.style.backgroundColor = '#f3f8aa';
    };
    tbRow[i].onmouseout = function() {
      this.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
    };
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with css itself.

```
#tfhover tr td {
    background-color:transparent
}
#tfhover tr:hover td:not(.link) {
  background-color:#f3f8aa;
}
```

Or

```
/*#tfhover tr {
    background-color:transparent;
}*/ /*This rule is not needed since default background is transparent*/
#tfhover tr:hover td  {
  background-color:#f3f8aa;
}
#tfhover tr td.link{
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ckF2h/)**

Comment: You may want to use [`border-collapse:collapse;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse) with this if you find you're getting breaks in the colour between cells

Comment: @PSL Your code is working but I miss to include my css in that tr. Can you please take a look again in my updated question? Pardon me

Comment: @user3097736 You should not use duplicate id. Just use them as classnames

Comment: @user3097736 Here is the demo with your code.. http://jsfiddle.net/aG32J/ Just change it according to how you need it.

Comment: @user3097736 It is working in my demo. You must be missing something in your original page. You should try to diagnose it. Or put together a fiddle showing that it is not working.

Comment: @PSL the onmouseover is still there in my code. :( But in fiddle it's working.

Comment: @user3097736 Remove the javascript. You dont need it. You only need the css as i mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @PSL it works, but the problem is I have another table inside of my table. And it affects my nested table. It has no class name but it's affected by the css

Comment: @user3097736 then use immediate descendant selector like this. http://jsfiddle.net/ZY7BG/ You should do some research... :)

Comment: @PSL thanks, I gonna work with my mini problems :). Just last one, how to connect two class name. " #tfhover td.none, td.nested " just like this?

Comment: @user3097736 You are welcome.. You should do `#tfhover td.none, #tfhover td.nested`

Answer (score 0):

Just use some if statement logic to determine whether or not to add the mouseover events to the elements.

It looks like your 1st column is always a link, so as you run through the for loop, check if it is the first column, if it is, do not add the mouseover event.

By the way you probably need a nested loop in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
$(function() {
  $("td").each(function() {
    if($(this).attr("id") != "none") {
      $(this).mouseover(function() {
         $(this).css("background-color","#f3f8aa");
         })
          .mouseout(function() { $(this).css("background-color","transparent"); });
        }
     });
 });
```

Comment: (Why JS?) `$(this).attr("id")` is wrong. You must use `.` classnames. `none` should be *string* `"none"` and btw jQuery has the `:not()` selector for that use. And even with ID `this.id` is native and simpler. And you don't need all the `mouseover, mouseout` stuff which should be btw `mouseenter mouseleave`, but you can use just the `.hover()` method and toggle colors in one line of code.

Comment: Sorry,i'm not jQuery expert :-)

Comment: Also you don't need the `.each()` cause `$('td')` is already a *collection* of all the needed elements so just `$('#tfhover td:not(".none")').hover(function( ev ){` is quite enough.

Comment: Than inside the function `$(this).css({backgroundColor: ev.type.match('t')?"#f3f8aa":"transparent"});` would be awesome. But crazy cause we have CSS for all of that :)